# Function modifier seems to be not working

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, modifiers

I have a simple contract as below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

/* Contract accepting ethers during 10 minutes */
contract SimpleBidding {

    address receivingAccount;
    uint deadline;

    struct Asset {
        string name;
        uint price;
        uint barcode;
        uint stockCount;
    }

    struct Vendor {
        string name;
        address account;
        Asset asset;
    }

    Vendor[] vendors;
    uint numberOfRequests = 0;
    event AssetRequested(uint barcode);
    event AssetSold(uint vendorID);
    event RequestProcessed();

    /*  at initialization, setup the owner */
    function SimpleBidding(address _vendor0, address _vendor1, address _vendor2) {
        // create 2 assets
        Asset memory asset0 = Asset("Asset", 11, 1234, 1);
        vendors.push(Vendor("Vendor0", _vendor0, asset0));

        Asset memory asset1 = Asset("Asset", 12, 1234, 3);
        vendors.push(Vendor("Vendor1", _vendor1, asset1));

        Asset memory asset2 = Asset("Asset", 10, 1234, 1);
        vendors.push(Vendor("Vendor2", _vendor2, asset2));

        // set the deadline as 10 minutes
        deadline = now + 10 * 1 minutes;
    }  

    function getVendor(uint id) constant returns (string name, address acc, string assetName, uint assetPrice, uint barcode, uint numAssets) {
        var vendor = vendors[id];
        name = vendor.name;
        acc = vendor.account;
        assetName = vendor.asset.name;
        assetPrice = vendor.asset.price;
        barcode = vendor.asset.barcode;
        numAssets = vendor.asset.stockCount;
    }

    function requestAsset(uint barcode) {
        numberOfRequests++;  
        AssetRequested(barcode);
    }

    modifier afterAssetRequested() { if (numberOfRequests == 0) throw; _;}

    function processRequest() afterAssetRequested {
        // find the cheapest vendor who has the asset in its stock
        uint minIndex = 0;
        for (uint i=1; i<vendors.length; i++) {
            if (vendors[i].asset.price < vendors[minIndex].asset.price) {
                if (vendors[i].asset.stockCount > 0) {
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (vendors[minIndex].asset.stockCount > 0) {
            // the cheapest vendor sells the asset
            vendors[minIndex].asset.stockCount--;
            AssetSold(minIndex);
        }

        // wait for new asset request
        numberOfRequests = 0;

        RequestProcessed();
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the time limit has been reached and ends the contract */
    function dispose() afterDeadline {
        suicide(receivingAccount);
    }
}
```

It works fine on online compiler. Functions work, events are generated. Then I try to use it via geth. I created a JS file as below with input paramaters to the constructor and watching mechanisms for the events.

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0],"Node01Account00")
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[1],"Node01Account01")
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[2],"Node01Account02")
var _vendor0 = eth.accounts[1] ;
var _vendor1 = eth.accounts[2] ;
var _vendor2 = eth.accounts[2] ;
// contract code
var simplebidding_sol_simplebiddingContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"}],"name":"requestAsset","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"dispose","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"id","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getVendor","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"acc","type":"address"},{"name":"assetName","type":"string"},{"name":"assetPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"},{"name":"numAssets","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"processRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_vendor0","type":"address"},{"name":"_vendor1","type":"address"},{"name":"_vendor2","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"}],"name":"AssetRequested","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"vendorID","type":"uint256"}],"name":"AssetSold","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"RequestProcessed","type":"event"}]);
var simplebidding_sol_simplebidding = simplebidding_sol_simplebiddingContract.new(
   _vendor0,
   _vendor1,
   _vendor2,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
     // configure the event to watch for changes
     var event = simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.AssetSold();
     event.watch(function(error, result){
       if (!error)
         console.log("[Asset sold: Vendor: " + result.args.vendorID + " ]");
     });
     var event2 = simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.RequestProcessed();
     event2.watch(function(error, result){
       if (!error)
         console.log("[Request processed!]");
     });
     var event3 = simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.AssetRequested();
     event2.watch(function(error, result){
       if (!error)
         console.log("[Asset:" + result.args.barcode + " requested!]");
     });
    }
 })
```

After I deploy the contract via `loadScript("SimpleBidding.js")`, I am calling the `requestAsset()` function via `simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset.call(1234)`. However nothing happens. No log is generated as I programmed in the js file.

It seems to me that may be also the modifier `afterAssetRequested()` is also not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I played around briefly in Remix and it seemed from looking at the code that it's necessary to send a transaction to `requestAsset()` first, then `processRequest()`, so I did it in that order. The transaction was processed without error. I don't think the result (0x) is exactly what you want, but that's another matter.

It looks to me like if you miss the `requestAsset()` step and do `processRequest()`, then numberOfRequests==0 and the `modifier` throws, by design. You get the "nothing happens" sort of experience. The modifier is doing its job when the function `throws` because conditions aren't right.

Here's a pic from remix showing inputs and log events.

Hope it helps.

[image]

**Unrelated side note.** `processRequest()` has a `for` loop that looks like it might be unbounded. This is a potentially *show-stopping* issue because each iteration through the loop costs gas and there's a hard block gas limit, meaning this will fail if the number of vendors is over a certain limit.

Comment: Thank you Rob, for your time and your comments. However, I mentioned also question that "It works fine on online compiler. Functions work, events are generated.". As I understand the online compiler does not dealing with the modifiers, right? You need to activate the functions by clicking on their buttons. Or is there a way to see if modifiers are working or not using the online compiler?

Comment: On the other hand, I only want to call the `requestAsset()` function from the client, and let the `processRequest()` function activated thanks to the modifier. However, using geth, I am not having the result I am expecting. Normally, when I call `requestAsset()`, the `numOfRequests` variable becomes more than zero, and thus the modifier should make the other function work. Am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by _send a transaction to requestAsset() first, then processRequest()_? In online compiler, you click on the button of the function, but how do you do that in geth?

Comment: @hookercookerman is right about dropping.call() on the JavaScript because that explicitly say don't update the chain state ... hence the chain state is unaffected. No, your off re: Remix and modifiers. Remix respects the bytecode and the modifier is in play. Thankfully not another variable to think about. I too did contract.requestAsset(1234) via remix. No ".call()" for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't know how to send a transaction to a specific function of a contract from a client like geth (not from Remix).

Comment: Try simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset(1234)

Comment: I have already tried it. That's why after I used '. call()'.

Comment: Hi, I discovered how to do it, you need to use `simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset.sendTransaction(1234, {from: eth.coinbase})` for non-constant functions.

Answer (score 1):

No call my friend as that is just an RPC call state transition require normal send transaction. Calls are for constant modifiers on functions

Comment: lol ... yes. Quite right.

Comment: How can I send a transaction and call the function I want? I only know normal sendTransaction method, and it calls the fallback function by default.

Comment: Hi, I discovered how to do it, you need to use `simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset.sendTransaction(1234, {from: eth.coinbase})` for non-constant functions.